# QT OpenGL ,Vertex Buffer Object and GLEW?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt4, glew

I am in the process of migrating my old openGL code (immediate mode) to Vertext-Buffer-Objects.
I realized that I need to use OpenGL3 API calls (GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object) for this.
So I was going to use GLEW as extension loading library.

My question is , is there a special way to initialize QGLWidget for OpenGL3 contexT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by an "OpenGL 3 context"?

You can get OpenGL support for version 3.1 or greater by normal context creation. Now, if you want a *[core OpenGL context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts)*, which implements the core specification, then you have to do a bit of work.

Note that a compatibility context is perfectly fine. It still does everything a core context does; you don't *have* to do any of the following to use buffer objects.

Oh, and buffer objects are not an extension anymore. Use the core functions, not the extension functions you see in `GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object`.

Note: the following is for QT 4.7 or above:

You must be at least semi familiar with `QGLFormat`; you need one in order to create a `QGLWidget`. Just call `QGLFormat::setProfile` on that object with `QGLFormat::CoreProfile`.

Sadly, QT does not allow you to specify a specific version. But that should be enough to get a core OpenGL profile, assuming your hardware implements OpenGL 3.2 or better.

Comment: you said to use core functions for BufferObjects.But still ,I have to use GLEW right ?  I mean , the normal gl.h shipped with Windows7 doesn't have those API calls right?

Comment: @umanga: You don't have to use GLEW specifically. But you do need to load the function pointers from OpenGL, and GLEW does that. I'm saying to use `glGenBuffers`, not `glGenBuffersARB` as in the extension.

Comment: thanks for the answer.i think i mixed up big time.I don't really need OpenGL3 support for VBO objects right ?

Comment: @unmanga: No, you don't. Vertex Buffer Objects have been around as a extension for quite some time now. The extension was written against OpenGL-1.4.

Comment: @umanga: The extension was adopted into the core in GL 1.5, so it has been part of OpenGL for a long time.